# White overlay over an image

Tags: html, css

Hi i am aware that you can add a greyscale filter on an image, but would it be possible for a white overlay using the filter setting. I have to do it through css without the need for another div, to be absolute positioned over the image, with a white background and opacity setting changed. Just a simple image within a a tag:

```
<a href="#">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
</a>
```

css is basic

```
a img{
     display:block;
     max-width:100%;
     height:auto
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code? one way is you can use `pseudo` element of the parent  and set it `absolute` with `100%` `width` and `height`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/savo2ska/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1:

You may use the `:after` psuedo-element. For example, add a class of `white-out` to your `<a>` element, and then use the following CSS:

```
a.white-out {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
    a.white-out:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yorg0Lzq/)

---

### Solution 2:

Alternatively, you can try setting a white background on your `<a>` element, and reducing the opacity of the `<img />` inside. For example:

```
a.white-out {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
}
    a.white-out img {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yorg0Lzq/1/)